# hide an attribute initially at startup in web application

Tags: jsf-2, show-hide

I am working on a JSF application.
I have recently faced a problem, that how to `hide` any `attribute` at the start-up of the application.
For **Example** -
I have a `h:panelGrid` attribute for displaying table, but I want to show this table only when a `checkbox` is clicked, Here I am able to made it working for show/hide but only from second time onwards.
What I want is to hide this table using `h:panelGrid` when application loads this view, the later part as I told I have achieved.
It would be grateful if somebody cite it for general hide at start-up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...somehow like this
in panelGrid set `style="visibility:hidden"`
and in checkBox, call javascript function and in there set

```
if (show) 
{
    obj.style.display = "block";
    obj.style.visibility="visible";
} 
else 
{
    obj.style.display = "none";
}
```

It does the trick.
Thanks Petr for help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean attribute in the ManagedBean which this page uses and set it to false (for example in PostConstruct method). Then use it as a rendered attribute of your `<h:panelGrid>` and it's going to be defaultly hidden.

let's say

```
 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 public class Bean {
     private boolean visible = false;
     //setters and getters
 }
 //later on page
 <h:panelGrid rendered="#{bean.visible} />
```

Comment: `rendered` attribute is used for telling, whether it can be rendered again or not.  Which is just opposite of what I want. I want to hide it initially then show/hide by using javascript, the later part I've done.

Comment: Then just set style="visibility:hidden" on your h:panelPanel and you will be able to change it with javascript later

Comment: it will always makes it hidden.

Comment: If u can tell me, how can I call javascript function from panelGrid WHILE loading.